# Overriding a MooTools event with jQuery.click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools, jquery-events, preventdefault

I have a library function, that I cannot change, which uses MooTools to attach an event.

```
$(document.body).addEvents({
    "mousedown:relay(a.className)": function (a, b) {
        if (!a.rightClick) {
            //do something
        }
        return false
});
```

I'm not too familiar with MooTools, but I've tried everything I can think of to override this with a `jQuery.click()` event.

I've tried attaching a listener to `.className`, its parents (a few levels up), and even the whole `body`; each time, I use `function (e) { e.preventDefault() }` in my `click` event.

I've always assumed the `preventDefault()` would always prevent all default events associated with the newly-triggered event.

Can anyone enlighten me as to why my event override isn't working?

// EDIT

I'm not looking to use MooTools because we will probably port everything to jQuery (or at least not MooTools) in the future. I guess I'll have to, though, if there's no other way.

// EDIT 2

I've tried `jQuery.off()` in several different ways, including 
`$j('body').off('click mousedown','.className');` and it still fails to remove the MooTools event.

// EDIT 3

I decided it was best to just not mess with MooTools; I've changed the classname so the MooTools doesn't do anything and just replicated what happened in the `//do something` part of the code above.

I have a feeling I can't do anything with the click event because of the `return false` at the end of the MooTools event listener.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why do you have to override the event?  if you already have a click event, why can't you handle additional logic there?

Comment: I can't add or change the library (the code using MooTools) and I need to only let it run if some new conditions exist.

Comment: If you want to prevent that code from running, can't you simply [remove the events](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Event#Element:removeEvents)?

Comment: I'll add this to my question, but I'm looking to move away from MooTools so that, when we remove it from the library in the future, I won't have to go back and port this, too.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what version of JQuery you are using, you could try `off` (JQuery 1.7 or later) or `unbind` to remove the MooTools event handlers.

I am not sure how they work behind the scenes but I assume they will remove event handlers regardless of how they were bound the event.  You could then apply your own event handlers using JQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/off/

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: I just tried both of these, and they don't work. I'll try a few more things and update this accordingly.

Comment: Updated the original question with one of the things I've tried for this.

Comment: @charlieg are you sure the events are not being bound after you run `off`.  One way to test these definitively is to run `off` in your console after everything has executed.

Comment: That's how I was testing it, yeah :(